# delete custom displaytemplate files error Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have custom Display template Folder in master page Gallery. {Sitecollection/_catalogs/Masterpage/Display templates/filter/customFilters}. There is 10 refinement html and js files. I want to delete this.

I try this Code

```
SPFolder filterItemtemplateFolder = web.GetFolder("_catalogs/masterpage/display templates/Filters/customFilters");
if (filterItemtemplateFolder.ItemCount > 0)
{
    foreach (SPFile file in filterItemtemplateFolder.Files)
    {
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            file.Recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

But iam getting Collection enumeration error. I think the Problem is when the html file is deleted automatically the corresponding js file also will be deleted so the Collection is the same ?.

How can delete files in this Folder and also delete only specific files with filename ?.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `Collection was modified` error because you are using a `foreach` directly on the `Files` collection of the folder, so when you delete a file out of `SPFolder.Files`, then that modifies the `Files` collection and the next time the `foreach` tries to see where it should be while enumerating `Files`, it runs into a problem.

If you are trying to delete everything in the folder, why not just delete the folder itself?

```
SPFolder filterItemtemplateFolder = web.GetFolder("_catalogs/masterpage/display templates/Filters/customFilters");
filterItemtemplateFolder.Delete();
```

If you really need to preserve the folder, but delete all the files inside, the way I usually go about something like that is to refer to the items in the collection by their index (by using a regular `for` loop), so that you are not referring to the collection itself in a `foreach` line, *and* you have to keep in mind that every time you delete something from the collection, the total number of items in the collection is reduced by one, so what used to be at index `1` is now at index `0`, what used to be at index `2` is now at `1`, etc., so in order to not skip over items as your index increases, you have to do a *reverse* `for` loop:

```
SPFolder filterItemtemplateFolder = web.GetFolder("_catalogs/masterpage/display templates/Filters/customFilters");
if (filterItemtemplateFolder.ItemCount > 0)
{
    for (int i = filterItemtemplateFolder.Files.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        SPFile file = filterItemtemplateFolder.Files[i];
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            file.Recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to delete specific files based on their name, you could do the same thing, just check the name in your loop:

```
SPFolder filterItemtemplateFolder = web.GetFolder("_catalogs/masterpage/display templates/Filters/customFilters");
if (filterItemtemplateFolder.ItemCount > 0)
{
    for (int i = filterItemtemplateFolder.Files.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        SPFile file = filterItemtemplateFolder.Files[i];
        if (file.Exists && file.Name.Contains("delete me"))
        {
            file.Recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

OR, if it makes more sense, you could target the files directly:

```
string[] fileNamesToDelete = [ "deleteThis.js", "deleteThat.js" ];
foreach (string fileName in fileNamesToDelete)
{
    SPFile templateToDelete = web.GetFile("_catalogs/masterpage/display templates/Filters/customFilters/" + fileName);
    if (templateToDelete.Exists)
    {
        templateToDelete.Recycle();
    }
}
```